# Defining Variable Get in PHP

Tags: php

Im just new and still learning PHP.

Im trying to make a simple PHP for connecting and doing basic syntax insert, delete,select and update but I encountered an error `Undefined Variable: Get in C:/wamp/www/sql`. Is there something I missed?

Here is what i got:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$port = "3306";
$dbname = "student";



$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $port);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM info";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "ID: " . $row["studentid"]. " Name: " . $row["fname"]. " " .         $row["lname"]." <a href = delete.php? uid=".$row["studentid"]."> Delete</a> |  
  <a href = test.php?     euid=".$row['studentid']."&elname".$row['lname']."&efname".$row['fname']."> Edit     </a> <br/>" ;
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
<form action ="insert.php" method="POST">
<input type ="text" name="fname">
<input type ="text" name="lname">
<input type ="submit"value="Submit">
</form>

<form action ="update.php" method="POST">
<input type ="hidden" name="ID"<?php echo"value=".$GET["studentid"];?>> //I get the error from here
<input type ="text" name="fname"<?php echo"value=".$GET['fname'];?>>
<input type ="text"name="lname"<?php echo"value=".$GET['lname'];?>>. // until here
<input type ="submit"value="Update">
</form>



<?php
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Edit: Here is the other one im having trouble with.I get there error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in` How to fix it?. In this part of code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['xID']))
{
<form action ="update.php" method="POST">
<input type ="hidden" name="ID"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xID'];?>>
<input type ="text" name="fname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xfname'];?>>
<input type ="text"name="lname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xlname'];?>>.
<input type ="submit"value="Update">
}
else
{
}
</form>
?>
```

Comment: There is no variable `$GET` maybe you meant `$_GET`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you using get as wrong, its not `$GET`, its `$_GET`, chenge your code like this.

```
<form action ="update.php" method="GET">
     <input type ="hidden" name="ID"<?php echo"value=".$_GET["studentid"];?>> //I get the error from here
     <input type ="text" name="fname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['fname'];?>>
    <input type ="text"name="lname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['lname'];?>>. // until here
     <input type ="submit"value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: If u need, you can change `GET` to `POST`.

Comment: Note that if the form is not yet submitted it will still raise the warning.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable he should check with `if(isset())`.

Comment: Or accept 'undefined index' warnings (which i sometimes do although it's bad practice).

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju can you help me with `if(isset())`? Im trying to learn to use it but i got some problem

Comment: we use that coz, if sometimes, if we r not getting any value, example add name to submit button, then in php code add `if(iisset($_GET["submit"]) && !empty($_GET["submit"])) {
// we allow to execute our code.
}`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I read about it and I already understand its use now, but when I try to insert it in my code particularly in this part 

`<?php
if(isset($_GET['xID']))
{
<form action ="update.php" method="POST">
<input type ="hidden" name="ID"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xID'];?>>
<input type ="text" name="fname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xfname'];?>>
<input type ="text"name="lname"<?php echo"value=".$_GET['xlname'];?>>.
<input type ="submit"value="Update">
else
}` 

it returns me and error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'`
Can you me help me with this?

Comment: closing braces after else??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju my braces are complete.. check at the top I edit it to include what I'm referring to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92075/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-kielou).

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I already edited my post at top so you can see what im referring to.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax error (it's `$_GET` and not `$GET`), you are also using POST as method to send the data, be sure to learn the difference between `GET` and `POST` methods.

You should also know that you can use use `$_REQUEST`to retrieve the data sent via both `GET` and `POST`.

The following should be correct:

```
<form action ="update.php" method="GET">
     <input type ="hidden" name="ID"<?php echo"value=".$_REQUEST["studentid"];?>>
     <input type ="text" name="fname"<?php echo"value=".$_REQUEST['fname'];?>>
    <input type ="text"name="lname"<?php echo"value=".$_REQUEST['lname'];?>>.
     <input type ="submit"value="Update">
</form>
```